# Cron -bash: 0: command not found

Tags: linux, cron

I feel very dumb but why does it not work when I just want to use a simple Linux command in a crontab?

```
0 0 0 * * ? ls /data/synology/multimedia/movies > /data/storage/backup/movies.txt 2>&1
```

This ends up in `-bash: 0: command not found`. Why is ls not found? What is wrong?

Comment: What does '?' mean?

Comment: Assuming your cron implementation assigns some meaning to `?`, it looks like there is an error in your script.

Comment: Most likely your script uses some bashisms that are not applied when the script is run via cron, and your usage of `[` or `test` or `$((` or similar is flawed.  Show the content of the script.  (After minimizing it to the smallest case that reproduces the problem.)

Comment: It seems I misunderstood something. I have seen some examples on this page here: https://www.konordo.com/blog/how-test-cron-centos here the person also just simply executes a command like /bin/echo and I thought it would also work with ls. That is my command. The ? came out of a formatter.

Comment: @CptDayDreamer what if you tried /bin/ls

Comment: Are you per chance trying to run the crontab file as a script? How are you testing?

Comment: @BenjaminW. jep that was the problem. The link above was misleading. My cron works.

Answer (score 1):

You are not specifying a command to bash. It thinks 0 is the name of the program you want to run.

Answer (score 0):

try this one. use absolute path of `ls` .

first of all find the absolute path with `whereis ls` then add `crontab` as below.

```
0 0 0 * * /bin/ls /data/synology/multimedia/movies > /data/storage/backup/movies.txt 2>&1
```